# Import external Module in app.module.ts

Tags: angular

I'm wondering about modules in Angular 4, If I have this module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    OneComponent
  ],
})
export class OneModule { }
```

And in my app.modules.ts I use this module in the imports

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    OneModule
    ...
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Is that mean the `OneComponent` is declared in the App Module?

I'm facing a problem with TimeAgoModule package, If I put it in the OneModule imports, then the OneComponent should see the time, but it said that time is not defined, and If I move the OneComponent from OneModule declarations to AppModule declarations everything is fine. What exactly the idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `export` OneComponent.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    ...
  ],
  exports: [OneComponent],
  declarations: [
    OneComponent
  ],
})
export class OneModule { }
```

by exporting a `component` , you tell angular module that this specific `component` can be used outside the module and will be available for reuse in other modules.